# How do I run a XMLHttpRequest that relies on another XMLHttpRequest?

Tags: javascript, django, ajax

I am setting up a social media website where there are posts and comments on posts.
The posts and comments are requested using XMLHttpRequest (with a Django, Python backend)

here is my post loading code:

```
const xhr = new XMLHttpRequest()
const method = 'GET'
const responseType = 'json'
const url = '/posts'
xhr.responseType = responseType
xhr.open(method, url)
xhr.onload = function() {
    const serverResponse = xhr.response
    onst listItems = serverResponse
    for(var i = 0; i < listItems.length; i++){
        var postObj = listItems[i]
        var currentItem = formatPostElement(postObj)
        finalPostStr += currentItem // with additional HTML code
    }
    postsElement.innerHTML = finalPostStr
}
        
xhr.send() // trigger the request
```

This is my code for loading the comments:

```
        const xhr = new XMLHttpRequest()
        const method = 'GET'
        const responseType = 'json'
        const url = '/comments' + post_id
        xhr.responseType = responseType
        xhr.open(method, url)
        var input = ''
        xhr.load = function() {
            const serverResponse = xhr.response
            const commentItems = serverResponse
            for(var q = 0; q < commentItems.length; q++){
                input += commentItems[q].content
            }
            commentContainerElement.innerHTML = input
            console.log(input)

        }
        xhr.send()
```

The code for the posts grabs every post available in the database. The code for the comments grabs all the comments that are related for a post with `post_id`. So how can I run the comments request code and have it show with every respective post?

Comment: I don't understand your question. What do you currently have (maybe you can add a screenshot of the result). Consider also posting your django view to better understand what return each request.

Comment: Maybe in your view, you can add the comments of a post directly inside the "Get Post" response ? You would only have to do one request per post instead of two.